# Rotating image using rotation matrix in Python

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library, array-broadcasting

So I am trying to create a code that can rotate an image counterclockwise using Python by implementing the rotation matrix. This code is supposed to rotate the image counterclockwise, but why does it rotate the picture in a clockwise motion?

```
import math
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('squidward.jpg')
Im = np.array(img)

angle = 30
# Define the most occuring variables
angle=math.radians(angle)                               #converting degrees to radians
cosine=math.cos(angle)
sine=math.sin(angle)
height=Im.shape[0]                                   #define the height of the image
width=Im.shape[1]                                    #define the width of the image

# Define the height and width of the new image that is to be formed
new_height  = round(abs(Im.shape[0]*cosine)+abs(Im.shape[1]*sine))+1
new_width  = round(abs(Im.shape[1]*cosine)+abs(Im.shape[0]*sine))+1

# define another image variable of dimensions of new_height and new _column filled with zeros
Rot_Im=np.zeros((new_height,new_width,Im.shape[2]))

# Find the centre of the image about which we have to rotate the image
original_centre_height   = round(((Im.shape[0]+1)/2)-1)    #with respect to the original image
original_centre_width    = round(((Im.shape[1]+1)/2)-1)    #with respect to the original image

# Find the centre of the new image that will be obtained
new_centre_height= round((((new_height)+1)/2)-1)        #with respect to the new image
new_centre_width= round((((new_width)+1)/2)-1)          #with respect to the new image

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        #co-ordinates of pixel with respect to the centre of original image
        y0=Im.shape[0]-1-i-original_centre_height                   
        x0=Im.shape[1]-1-j-original_centre_width
                     

        #co-ordinate of pixel with respect to the rotated image
        new_y0=round(x0*sine+y0*cosine)
        new_x0=round(x0*cosine-y0*sine)

        '''since image will be rotated the centre will change too, 
           so to adust to that we will need to change new_x and new_y with respect to the new centre'''
        new_y0=new_centre_height-new_y0
        new_x0=new_centre_width-new_x0

        # adding if check to prevent any errors in the processing
        if 0 <= new_x0 < new_width and 0 <= new_y0 < new_height and new_x0>=0 and new_y0>=0:
            Rot_Im[new_y0,new_x0,:]=Im[i,j,:]                          #writing the pixels to the new destination in the output image

pil_img=Image.fromarray((Rot_Im).astype(np.uint8))                       # converting array to image
pil_img.save("rotated_image.png")                                                 # saving the image
```

Answer (score 0):

Do -30 for counterclockwise. I think you will get the answer but it is too late i suppose